# Least Permission to add to Site Feed?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sitefeed

I have some site feeds in various sub sites that I would like site visitors to be able to contribute to for feedback purposes.  However, with just read permissions they cannot contribute to the site feed.

What is the least required permissions to grant the visitors to allow for site feed access?  Is it just edit (on the site feed), or do they need to edit and add items?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Site members is the minimum required permissions to add feeds to you site

Comment: That is the default contribute permission set correct?  I feel like that may be to many permissions, so I was wondering what part of the contribute permission set was required for participating in a site feed.